# Positioning a custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mapkit

I create a custom MKAnnoationView as follows:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView* customPinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                           initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

    UIImage *pinImage = [PowerPlantAnnotation getAnnotationImageForEnergySource:((PowerPlantAnnotation*)annotation).energySource];
    customPinView.image = pinImage;
    return customPinView;
}
```

I get the image that I want positioned more or less in the right spot, but not quite. My image looks like this:

[image]

I want the bottom point of the tear drop to point to my annotation map coordinate, like the standard pin view points to the map coordinate. How can I accomplish this? Currently it looks a bit more like my image is centered on the map coordinate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default annotation view center is placed at the annotation coordinate. To adjust view position set its [centerOffset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207-CH1-SW19) property:

```
annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, -annotationViewHeight/2);
```

Comment: in this case. the center of the view aligns at the exact coordinate position. The base of the pin of should be at the coordinate for accuracy.